# Access webViewState in ExtensionContext - VSCode Extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am developing a VSCode extension that has complex UI. To develop the view, I am using React. On user action on view I am saving the state using setState API of

```
private readonly vsCodeApi: WebviewApi<AppPropType>
```

This works fine and state is reloaded when extension is restarted in the workspace.

I have two problems:

1. I need functionality on explorer context menu, which requires data from WebView state. I am unable to access those properties either in extensionContext.globalState or workSpaceState.

   I tried

   ```
   context.globalState.get("appPropType")
   context.globalState.get("propofAppPropType")
   ```

   I also tried to explore the context values in console, but could not find it.
2. I also want WebViewState to be saved in globalState not in workSpaceState. Is there any way to mention setState to save in global not in workspace.